# caret::train: specify model-generation-parameters

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm using the `caret` library in R for model generation. I want to generate an `earth` (aka MARS) model and I want to specify the `degree` parameter for this model generation. According to the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf) (page 11) the `earth` method supports this parameter.

I get the following error message when specifying the parameter:

```
> library(caret)
> data(trees)
> train(Volume~Girth+Height, data=trees, method='earth', degree=1)
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "formal argument "degree" matched by multiple actual arguments"
```

How can I avoid this error when specifying the `degree` parameter?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] earth_3.2-3    plotrix_3.4    plotmo_1.3-1   leaps_2.9      caret_5.15-023
 [6] foreach_1.4.0  cluster_1.14.2 reshape_0.8.4  plyr_1.7.1     lattice_0.20-6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_2.15.0 grid_2.15.0     iterators_1.0.6
[5] tools_2.15.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out how to do it, joran led me into the right direction:

Create a new function which generates the training grid. This function must accept the two parameters `len` and `data`. In order to retrieve the original training grid, you can call the `createGrid` method provided by the `caret` package. You can then modify the grid to your needs. For example to neave the `nprune` parameter unchanged and add `degree` from 1 to 5 use the following code:

```
  createMARSGrid <- function(len, data) {
      g = createGrid("earth", len, data)
      g = expand.grid(.nprune=g$.nprune, .degree=seq(1,5))
      return(g)
  }
```

Then invoke it like this:

```
train(formula, data=data, method='earth', tuneGrid = createMARSGrid)
```

Comment: Thanks @theomega. This is very helpful. Do you know what the connection between `len` in `createGrid` and `tuneLength` (argument to `train`) is? Also, why does `createGrid` need to receive the data for certain models? (`?createGrid` does not say much on this)

Comment: Please ask a new question and I'll be happy to help you

Comment: Thanks theomega: Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839730/caret-errors-with-creategrid-for-rf-randomforest. I am still missing an answer clarifying the connection between `tuneLength` and the len parameter in `createGrid`, e.g. can they be used together? what is their relationship?

Answer (score 12):

I have always found the functions in **caret** both useful and somewhat maddening. Here's what's going on.

You're attempting to pass an argument to `earth` via the `...` argument to `train`. The documentation for `train` contains this description for that argument:

> arguments passed to the classification or regression routine (such as
>   randomForest). Errors will occur if values for tuning parameters are
>   passed here.

Tuning parameter, eh? Well, if you scroll down and examine the official list of tuning parameters for each model type, you'll see that for `earth`, they are `degree` and `nprune`.

So the issue here is that `train` is designed to automate some grid searching along tuning parameters, and the `...` argument is to be used for passing further arguments to the model fitting function *except* for those tuning parameters.

If you want to set the tuning parameters you'll need to use other arguments, like so:

```
train(Volume~Girth+Height, data=trees, method='earth',
      tuneGrid = data.frame(.degree = 1,.nprune = 5))
```

Note how the columns are named with leading periods. Also, it is frustrating that since the default value in `earth` for `nprune` is `NULL`, I'm not sure you can pass only the default values in this way. (Generally, setting things to `NULL` in data frames will simply remove them.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The problem is: How can I keep the 'nprune' to its default value? I looked it up in the source and found out that the default-value is calucated using private (non-callable) function `marsSeq` so it is not a fixed value. As you told, you can not leave it out.

Comment: See my answer below which provides a solution to my (and your) question.

Comment: Is the dot infront of the parameter names really necessary? For me, it works with and without it.