# Errors with createGrid for rf (randomForest) when using caret

Tags: r, random-forest

When I try to crate a grid of parameters for training with [caret](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/) I get various errors:

```
> my_grid <- createGrid("rf")
Error in if (p <= len) { : argument is of length zero

> my_grid <- createGrid("rf", 4)
Error in if (p <= len) { : argument is of length zero

> my_grid <- createGrid("rf", len=4)                                        
Error in if (p <= len) { : argument is of length zero
```

The documentation for createGrid says:

```
This function creates a data frame that contains a grid of
     complexity parameters specific methods.
Usage:
       createGrid(method, len = 3, data = NULL)
Arguments:
  method: a string specifying which classification model to use. See
          'train' for a full list.
     len: an integer specifying the number of points on the grid for
          each tuning parameter.
    data: the training data (only needed in the case where the 'method'
          is 'cforest', 'earth', 'bagEarth', 'fda', 'bagFDA', 'rpart',
          'svmRadial', 'pam', 'lars2', 'rf' or 'pls'). The outcome
          should be in a column called '.outcome'.
```

and gives the following examples which work correctly:

```
 createGrid("rda", 4)
 createGrid("lm")
 createGrid("nnet")
 
 ## data needed for SVM with RBF:
 ## Not run:
 
 tmp <- iris
 names(tmp)[5] <- ".outcome"
 head(tmp)
 createGrid("svmRadial", data = tmp, len = 4)
 ## End(Not run)
```

With this, what I am doing wrong?

#### Follow up question:

What is the connection between `len`  as an argument to `createGrid` and `tuneLength` in the argument for `train`? Can `len` and `tuneLength` they be used together? What is their relationship?

#### Other helpful threads:

In case  it helps, here is a thread describing how to use `createGrid` with `train` in `caret`: [caret::train: specify model-generation-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498477/carettrain-specify-model-generation-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pulled from the examples works fine for me (and noting that it fixes the problem that existed when you posted on Rhelp):

```
tmp <- iris
 names(tmp)[5] <- ".outcome"
 head(tmp)
 createGrid("svmRadial", data = tmp, len = 4)
#-------
     .sigma   .C
1 0.7500934 0.25
2 0.7500934 0.50
3 0.7500934 1.00
4 0.7500934 2.00
```

Edit:

```
>  createGrid("rf", data = tmp, len = 4)
randomForest 4.6-7
Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.

Attaching package: ‘randomForest’

The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:Hmisc’:

    combine

note: only 3 unique complexity parameters in default grid. Truncating the grid to 3 .

  .mtry
1     2
2     3
3     4
```

I say again: What problem remains?

Comment: Thanks. Please see the examples I tried at the top of the OP. I didn't say the examples provided in the documentation don't work.

Comment: Ok (+1) thanks! I didn't know I was supposed to pass data to rf . The Usage part of the documentation said `data=NULL`, which made me think it was optional. By the way, do you know the connection between (1) the argument `tuneLength` in `train` and (2) the grid passed to `train` via `tuneGrid`? (see follow up question)

Comment: As I read the documentation there would be no connection. It says that one or the other is used to construct candidate parameters. `tuneGrid` lets you specify the locations, while `tuneLength` lets you specify their number.

Comment: `createGrid()` no longer exists in caret

Comment: Yes. This has already been noted on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275173/creategrid-function-from-caret-package-was-it-removed However if you want the code it's still here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/caret/R/createGrid.R?view=markup&root=caret&pathrev=43 ...or... https://github.com/dalpozz/caretUtils/blob/master/createGrid.R