# createGrid function from caret package - Was it removed?

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm using `caret` package (version 6.0-24) in R (version 3.0.2). The function `createGrid` was actually removed?  In `caret` version 5.17-7 the function remains.

Answer (score 4):

the function *createGrid* was removed from the version 6.0-24  (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf)

Comment: The models are now maintained in separate list objects and each of these has its own `grid` element. For example, see `getModelInfo("pls", FALSE)[[1]]$grid`.